# Save table to hive using jdbc: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:40 cannot recognize input near '"Name"' 'TEXT'

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to save a spark dataframe to Hive, using JDBC in PySpark, but I keep getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling o343.jdbc.
: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:40 cannot recognize input near '"_1"' 'TEXT' ',' in column name or constraint
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:267)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:253)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:313)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:253)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeUpdate(HiveStatement.java:490)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createTable(JdbcUtils.scala:881)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:791)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:40 cannot recognize input near '"_1"' 'TEXT' ',' in column name or constraint
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:348)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:199)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:262)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:260)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:575)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:561)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:315)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:566)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1557)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1542)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TServlet.doPost(TServlet.java:83)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftHttpServlet.doPost(ThriftHttpServlet.java:208)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 1:40 cannot recognize input near '"_1"' 'TEXT' ',' in column name or constraint
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1870)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1817)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1812)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.compileAndRespond(ReExecDriver.java:126)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:197)
    ... 35 more
```

This is my code:

```
properties = {"user": self.user, "password": self.pwd, "driver": self.driver}
df.write.jdbc(url=self.url, table=target, mode=mode, properties=properties)
```

This is the dataframe I'm trying to save:

```
columns = ["language","users_count"]
data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
rdd = sp.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
dfFromRDD1 = rdd.toDF()
```

My driver jar version is: hive-jdbc-3.1.2-standalone (the latest)

On the other hand, when I try to read a simple table in Hive, that I already saved from another source, this is how result looks like:

[image]

But the actual result should look like:

[image]

The code I'm using for reading:

```
sdf_reader = (
        spark.read.format("jdbc")
        .option("url", self.url)
        .option("dbtable", "({}) a".format(sql))
        .option("user", self.user)
        .option("password", self.pwd)
        .option("driver", self.driver)
    )
    sdf_reader.options(**options)
    sdf = sdf_reader.load()
```